# Javascript function returning undefined even though console.log shows correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've checked other questions that seem to be duplicates but none of them have solved my problem. I have this simple function that loops through an array of rule objects and returns the one with the matching "type":

```
$ctrl.findRule = function(ruleName){
    $ctrl.rules.forEach(function(rule){
        if(rule.type === ruleName){
            console.log("returning rule: " + rule.type);
            return rule;
        }
    });
    return null;
};
```

I call this function as follows:

```
var wordCountRule = $ctrl.findRule("word_count");
console.log(wordCountRule);
```

I see on the console `returning rule: word_count` and then the `console.log(wordCountRule)` displays `undefined`. I have tried everything and I have no idea why this is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're returning the value from the inner `forEach` handler function, not your outer `findRule()` function.

To fix this you could define a variable to hold the return value and amend that within the inner scope:

```
$ctrl.findRule = function(ruleName) {
  var returnVal = null;
  $ctrl.rules.forEach(function(rule) {
    if (rule.type === ruleName) {
      returnVal = rule;
    }
  });
  return returnVal;
};
```

However you should note that it you're looking for a single value you can use `find()` directly, without the need to loop explicitly:

```
$ctrl.findRule = function(ruleName) {
  return $ctrl.rules.find(function(rule) {
    return rule.type === ruleName;
  });
};
```

Taking the above example a step further, by using ES6 syntax it can be reduced to just this:

```
$ctrl.findRule = ruleName => $ctrl.rules.find(rule => rule.type === ruleName);
```